# How can I checkout part of my cart on aliexpress?

Tags: aliexpress

If I have 10 items in my cart, and I just want to buy 5 right now, is there an easy way to do that?

From what I've seen, I can choose to pay for a specific seller, but not multiple (as long as it's not all).

On eBay, there's the `Save for later` which can be used to accomplish that. I prefer not to need to remove items from my cart for that purpose.

Comment: Downvoter - may explain?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is just a new feature but you can click check boxes as a subset of your shopping cart to order only part of it.

I added 100 items in my cart but only checked one. The order total is for just this one item.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Deleting items

To delete items from your Shopping Cart, simply follow the below steps:

1. Sign in to AliExpress
2. Click "Cart"
3. Select the items you want to delete and click the "Remove" button:
4. you can also click the "Remove All" button to delete all items in your Shopping Cart:

[image]
[image]

http://activities.aliexpress.com/adcms/help-aliexpress-com/deleting_adding_items.php

Comment: Hmmmm... Have you read my question? I never said I want to remove any item.